# Creating Cells for GridLayout in Java

Tags: java, layout, grid, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a grid for my snakes and ladders game in java, but I have a small problem where there is an unwanted space in the grids I've created

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get rid of that?

This is the code I have for the client side (Client.java):

```
//Initialize Grid Cells
private Cell[][] cell =  new Cell[10][10];          

//Create Grid Layout 
GridLayout GameBoard = new GridLayout(10, 10, 1, 1); //Create GridLayout             
GameArea.setLayout(GameBoard); //Add GridLayout  
GameArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(590,560));
GameArea.setOpaque(false); 

//Add Cells to Grid
for (int v = 0; v < 10; v++) 
for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
GameArea.add(cell[v][h] = new Cell(v, h, this));       

//Individual Image on Each Cell    
cell[1][0].add(new JLabel(GreenGrid));
```

This is the code I have for the cells(Cells.java), it also **extends JPanel**:

```
//Indicate the row and column of this cell in the board
private int GridRow;
private int GridColumn;

private Client parent;

public Cell(int GridRow, int GridColumn, Client GUI) {

  this.GridRow = GridRow;
  this.GridColumn = GridColumn;
  this.parent = GUI;

  setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.orange, 1));   // Set cell's border
  setBackground(Color.gray);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is here...

```
GridLayout GameBoard = new GridLayout(10, 10, 1, 1); //Create GridLayout
```

As described in the JavaDocs...

> public GridLayout(int rows,
>             int cols,
>             int hgap,
>             int vgap)
>
> Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns.
>   All components in the layout are given equal size.
>
> In addition, the horizontal and vertical gaps are set to the specified
>   values. Horizontal gaps are placed between each of the columns.
>   Vertical gaps are placed between each of the rows.
>
> One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any
>   number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.

What this means is, you are supplying the gap by supplying non-zero values to the `hgap` and `vgap` parameters.

If you used something like...

```
GridLayout GameBoard = new GridLayout(10, 10); //Create GridLayout
```

You would end up with something like...

[image: Base Grid]

As has already been mentioned, I would avoid using `GameArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(590,560));` and instead, override the `getPreferredSize` method the `Cell` class.  Because of the way that `GridLayout` works, this won't stop the cells from been resized, but this might be desirable anyway...

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes suggested by "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" and also tweaked the layout a little and got it working.  Instead of extending JPanel, I've replaced it with JButton and it worked fine somehow.  Thanks for the help and guidance

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your image, but I suspect that you have a layout issue. Does your Cell extend JPanel by the way? Do you set its layout manager or do you use the default FlowLayout?

Consider:

- You should not call `setPreferredSize(...)` on the GameBoard as that will then dictate your grid cell size, which is too big.
- Rather, the Cells themselves should be dictating the size of themselves and the entire grid.
- Consider having Cell override `getPreferredSize()` and returning the dimension of the JLabel's image (if one is present) or else returning the super's result.
- Be sure to call `pack()` on your top-level window after adding all components and before setting it visible.
- Consider having Cell use a BorderLayout and adding your JLabel to the BorderLayout.CENTER position so that it fills the cell (if that's what you want it to do).

For more help and better help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).