# JTextArea & JPanel different classes one window...is it possible?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jtextarea

So i have two classes:

```
public class TimeServer extends JPanel implements TimeVariables
{

public TimeServer() 
{

    JTextArea serverLog = new JTextArea();
    // Create a scroll pane to hold text area
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(serverLog);

    JPanel serverWin = new JPanel();

    serverWin.add(scrollPane);

}
```

and another class that has:

```
private JPanel mainWin = new JPanel();
private JPanel gridArea = new JPanel(); //hold cells

TimeServer serverWin = new TimeServer();

public class TimClient extends JFrame implements Runnable, TimeVariables 
{
    his.add(mainWin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainWin.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   // mainWin.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    //Create Grid
    gridArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            gridArea.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, this));

    gridArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));

    jlblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    jlblTitle.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16));
    jlblTitle.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));

    mainWin.add(gridArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainWin.add(serverWin, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    // Place the panel and the labels to the frame

    setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // implicit anyway

    add(jlblTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(mainWin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a frame
    TimClient frame = new TimClient("Time Client");
    //frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout)

    // Display the frame
    frame.setSize(620, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

all i want to do is **keep the server log and grid in the JPanel next to one another, could you explain how?**

also **how do i add the JPanel in the server class to the one in client?**

Here's a sketch of how i'd like it to look:
[image: sketch]

Comment: Removing the content of the question won't help anybody else the in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems above appear to stem from a bad Swing code practice, one that seems to be reinforced by Swing code generators (although I'm not sure if you're currently using this tool) and the official Swing tutorials, and that is:

- First and foremost, you should avoid having your Swing GUI classes extend JFrame as that unnecessarily paints your GUI code into a corner that requires a bit of effort to get out of.
- Instead gear your Swing GUI code towards making JPanels, panels which now can easily be placed into other JPanels, or into JFrames, JDialogs, JOptionPanes, swapped in CardLayouts,... wherever they are needed.
- Instead, create, fill, and pack your JFrames when they are needed.

So I suggest that you do just this:

- change your code above so that the classes do not extend JFrames, and instead create JPanels,
- Create a master JPanel that uses a BorderLayout
- Add your grid to the above, BorderLayout.CENTER
- Add your JTextArea-containing JScrollPane and its JPanel into the master JPanel in the BorderLayout.PAGE_END position.
- Create your JFrame to hold and display the master JPanel.

If you've done a good job of separated your GUI code from your logic code, then it should be easy to re-write the GUI code while keeping your same logic (or "model") code.

---

**Edit 2**
Regarding your changed question where now the first class extends JPanel, simply add that JPanel to your JFrame in the BorderLayout.LINE_END end (also known as BorderLayout.EAST) position.

Comment: i was planning on changing the server class from extending to jframe to jpanel. I'm not using any swing code generators...like i said a noob at programming getting to grips with it with minimal help :( apart from people on here :) thanks for your help :)

Comment: @YouSof: Regarding "not using Swing code generators" -- good for you! I'm all for using them after learning Swing, but you're doing it right to avoid them at this stage.

Comment: my plan is to change server class to jpanel and then keep client class as extending JFrame. but how would i add the jpanel in server to the frame in client? lol hope that makes sense

Comment: @YouSof: no, not really. If you are still having problems, better to clarify your problems with an edit to your original question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646015/creating-cells-for-gridlayout-in-java similar to what this user achieve in his picture that's what i'm aiming for

Comment: Full Of Eeels i'm having some issues when i go to run the client nothing appears :S i'm gonna post the code now

Comment: @YouSof: I strongly suggest that you create and post a [minimal compilable and runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let's not mess with these code snippets that no one can run or test. This will require serious effort from you, but if you need serious help, then it's the way to go. Please be sure to read the link fully to understand the requirements of this tool.

Comment: @YouSof: then you will need to find someone else to help you. If you desire my assistance, I ask you to respect my time constraints, as few of us volunteers (an important word and concept) have the free time to go through a complete program. Again, if you need our help, please read the link and give an attempt to create a minimal example.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much u don't understand, I'm gonna risk it and try solve this myself if i come to a point where I am like completely stuck i'll turn back to the community :) once again thanks for your help :)